# Aggregate table with dates and geographic coordinates

Tags: r, coordinates, aggregate

When `SOG` is 0 `Stops` gets 1. When the next `SOG` is 0 then `Stops` gets 2 and like this consecutively.

Now I want to group all the rows where `SOG != 0`. The trick is that I should have the following fields:

`MinTime`: minimum value of `BS` and `TS`, ie., date and time of boat arrival to port.

`MaxTime`: maximum value of `BS` and `TS`

`Duration`: difference between `MinTime` and `MaxTime`

`AveLat` and `AveLong`: Average Latitude and Longitude. Probably the most challenging. See formula at the bottom of the message.

This is what I have:

```
      MMSI       BS       TS      LAT     LONG SOG SIZE_A Stops
 247117300 6.4.2014 15:56:07 57.71432 11.96005   0     46     1
 247117300 6.4.2014 16:05:07 57.71433 11.96005   0     46     1
 247117300 6.4.2014 16:11:07 57.71432 11.96005   0     46     1
 247117300 6.4.2014 16:20:06 57.71433 11.96005   0     46     1
 247117300 6.4.2014 16:29:06 57.71433 11.96003   0     46     1
 247117300 6.4.2014 16:29:27 57.71433 11.96003   4     46     0
 247117300 6.4.2014 16:34:28 57.71433 11.96003   4     46     0
 247117300 6.4.2014 16:37:29 57.71433 11.96003   4     46     0
 247117300 6.4.2014 17:14:40 57.71433 11.96003   4     46     0
 247117300 6.4.2014 17:18:30 57.71432 11.96003   4     46     0
 247117300 6.4.2014 17:22:50 57.71433 11.96002   4     46     0
 247117300 6.4.2014 17:27:01 57.71432 11.96002   4     46     0
 247117300 6.4.2014 17:29:09 57.71435 11.96003   0     46     2
 247117300 6.4.2014 17:33:50 57.71435 11.96003   0     46     2
 247117300 6.4.2014 17:39:49 57.71437 11.96003   0     46     2
 247117300 6.4.2014 17:42:51 57.71435 11.96003   0     46     2
 247117300 6.4.2014 17:51:49 57.71433 11.96003   0     46     2
 247117300 6.4.2014 17:52:37 57.71432 11.96002   0     46     2
 247117300 6.4.2014 17:58:26 57.71212 11.95697   3     46     0
 247117300 6.4.2014 18:00:26 57.71047 11.95567   4     46     0
```

This is the desired result  (AveLAT and AveLONG are fake):

```
     MMSI       BS       TS      LAT     LONG SOG SIZE_A Stops           MinTime           MaxTime Duration_min   AveLAT   AveLON
247117300 6.4.2014 15:56:07 57.71432 11.96005   0     46     1 6.4.2014 15:56:07 6.4.2014 16:29:06           34 57.71432 11.96005
247117300 6.4.2014 17:29:09 57.71435 11.96003   0     46     2 6.4.2014 17:29:09 6.4.2014 17:52:37           23 57.71433 11.96003
```

Formula to get Average LAT and LONG:

1. LatToRadians: value*Pi/180
2. LongToRadians: value*Pi/180
3. X_cartesian: COS(LatToRadians) * COS(LongToRadians)
4. Y_Cartesian: COS(LatToRadians) * SIN(LongToRadians)
5. Z_Cartesian: SIN(LatToRadians)
6. AveX: SUM (X_Cartesian)/ all occurrences of X_Cartesian
7. AveY: SUM (Y_Cartesian)/ all occurrences of Y_Cartesian
8. AveZ: SUM (Z_Cartesian)/ all occurrences of Z_Cartesian
9. LAT: Inverse tangent (HYP, AveZ)
10. LONG: Inverse tangent (AveX, AveY)
11. HYP: Square root(AveX * AveX + AveY * AveY)
    12: LATMean: LAT * 180 / PI
12. LONGMean: LONG * 180 / PI

Comment: Thanks. It looks horrible though. Doesn't it? I thought an image would make the example more clear but I understand that this way one can copy-paste.

Comment: Oh. thanks @jbaums! Now I have to figure out how to do that :-)

Comment: See [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for info on formatting posts/comments.

Comment: I think I getting it using library(data.table): setDT(df)[, list(Min=min(TS), Max=max(TS) ), by=list(Stops, MMSI)] BUT I still have the problem with the coordinates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one idea using `dplyr` and `tidyr`. I wrote a custom function using your calculation information above. `foo` is your data. The last digits for average lat do not exactly match with your expected outcome. This may be possibly due to rounding.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

test <- filter(foo, Stops != 0) %>% # drop rows with Stop == 0 
        unite(dates, BS, TS, sep = " ") %>% #create date object
        mutate(dates = as.POSIXct(strptime(dates, format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S"))) %>%
        group_by(Stops) %>% # for each stop
        filter(dates == min(dates) | dates == max(dates)) %>% #select rows with min and max dates
        summarise(minTime = min(dates),
                  maxTime = max(dates),
                  duration = max(dates) - min(dates),
                  size_A = SIZE_A[1])

#  Stops             minTime             maxTime      duration size_A
#1     1 2014-04-06 15:56:07 2014-04-06 16:29:06 32.98333 mins     46
#2     2 2014-04-06 17:29:09 2014-04-06 17:52:37 23.46667 mins     46


### A custom function

cal <- function(x, y){            
            latToRadians <- x * pi / 180
            longToRadians <- y * pi / 180

            x_cartesian <- cos(latToRadians) * cos(longToRadians)
            y_cartesian <- cos(latToRadians) * sin(longToRadians)
            z_cartesian <- sin(latToRadians)

            aveX <- sum(x_cartesian) / length(x_cartesian)
            aveY <- sum(y_cartesian) / length(y_cartesian)
            aveZ <- sum(z_cartesian) / length(z_cartesian)

            hyp <- sqrt(aveX * aveX + aveY * aveY)
            lat <- atan2(aveZ, hyp)
            long <- atan2(aveY, aveX)

            latMean <- lat * 180 / pi
            longMean <- long * 180 / pi

            return(as.data.frame(cbind(latMean, longMean)))
        }

#### Get average long/lat using the function above

test2 <- foo %>%
         filter(Stops != 0) %>%
         group_by(Stops) %>%
         do(cal(.$LAT, .$LONG))

#  Stops  latMean longMean
#1     1 57.71433 11.96005
#2     2 57.71434 11.96003

### Combine test and test2
inner_join(test, test2) 

#Joining by: "Stops"
#Source: local data frame [2 x 7]

#  Stops             minTime             maxTime      duration size_A  latMean longMean
#1     1 2014-04-06 15:56:07 2014-04-06 16:29:06 32.98333 mins     46 57.71433 11.96005
#2     2 2014-04-06 17:29:09 2014-04-06 17:52:37 23.46667 mins     46 57.71434 11.96003
```

Comment: looks like you spent some time to write the code (plus one) :-)

Comment: @akrun Thank you. Yes, I invested some time for this one. Good training. Off to bed soon. Enjoy helping more people. I will check your answers tomorrow. :)